# Read file to custom class constructor

Tags: c#, .net, class, file-io, constructor

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Name One, 123, 13.88, 12.25
Name Two, 321, 12.56, 10.75
```

and I need to read it into an array (can not be array list) with a custom class that I have created that looks like:

```
class Stuff
{
    //Stuffconstructor (w/ args)
    public Stuff(string name, int number, decimal rate, double hours)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("this constructor has been called");
    }
}
```

I am not quite sure how to do this in c#.

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? Do you know how to open / read a file? Do you need help parsing the string? Please be specific.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of examples to be found of reading/parsing a text file in C#. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am not sure how to go about it. I want to be able to read the file line by line and put it into on object of my custom class so that the test from the file will be put into the array in the order: string, int, decimal, double. I am a beginner and have no idea how one would go about this

Comment: I have found examples but they seem to always be for the same type. if I just put it into a string array, I have no problem but I need the array to accept the different types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var parsedList = new List<Stuff>();
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\input.txt");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var lineSplit = line.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var stuff = new Stuff(lineSplit[0], Int32.Parse(lineSplit[1]), decimal.Parse(lineSplit[2]), double.Parse([3])  );
    parsedList.Add(stuff);
}
Stuff[]  arrayOfStuff = parsedList.ToArray();
```

Comment: :( spoon-feeding answers to "give me the code" questions makes me sad

Comment: My one problem with this solution is `ReadAllLines()`.  What if the text file is enormous?  There is no excuse to not use `ReadLines()`... you're already using a `foreach()`.

Comment: I can't use a list in this situation. do you have an alternative?

Comment: Using purely an array, instantiate it with `lines.length`, then swap the `foreach` for a `for(int i=0;`...

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks like it might be a very generic example... and you probably want something a bit more robust and expandable.  So let me introduce you to **reflection**.

**NOTE**

This solution uses **reflection**... which implies a few things:

- It's not for the faint of heart... This might look weird to a new programmer.
- Its not performance savvy.  Reflection can be a **LITTLE** slower than normal code...
- For simplicity, we assume you have **one public constructor**.
- Also for simplicity, we assume that the constructor only has arguments that have a method `Parse()` or is the type `String`.

**Solution**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Extract<T>(String path)
{
  var parseList = buildParser(typeof(T));

  foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path))
  {
    var tokens = line.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var args = parseList.Zip(tokens, (parser, value) => parser(value));

    yield return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args.ToArray());
  }
}

private static IEnumerable<Func<String, Object>> buildParser(Type t)
{
  // For now, we're going to assume you only have one public constructor.
  var ci = t.GetConstructors().First();

  foreach (var pi in ci.GetParameters())
  {
    var parser = fetchParseMethod(pi.ParameterType);
    Func<String, Object> boxingParser;

    if (parser != null)
      boxingParser = value => parser.Invoke(null, new Object[] { value });
    else
      boxingParser = value => value;

    yield return boxingParser;
  }
}

private static System.Reflection.MethodInfo fetchParseMethod(Type t)
{
  return (from mi in t.GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
          let parms = mi.GetParameters()
          where mi.Name == "Parse" && parms.Length == 1 && parms.First().ParameterType == typeof(String)
          select mi).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And then use the code like this:

```
foreach(var stuff in Extract<Struff>(@"C:\blah.txt"))
{
  // Do something with stuff
}
```

**Brief Overview**

This might look like quite a bit to take in... but it's actually quite simple:

1. We first look at the constructor of the desired type (`Stuff`)
2. We then go through each `ParameterType` of the constructor and grab the `Parse()` method for it.
3. We then use the `Parse()` method for each element of the text line to convert it to an `Object`.
4. With this, we can dynamically create an object (`Stuff`).

While this might be overkill for you... I had a good time creating it, and hopefully we all learn a little from it.  Also, this solution is extremely flexible.  If you later add arguments to the constructor, this will *automagically* pick it up.